# Tensorflow JS model fitting finishes instantly without doing anything

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow.js

Hi I am trying to build a conv neural network but I can't train it.

Here is the code:

```
model = tf.sequential();
model.add(tf.layers.conv2d({
    inputShape: [48, 48, 1],
    kernelSize: FILTER_SIZE,
    filters: 64,
    dataFormat: "channelsLast",
    activation: ActFunc.RELU
}));
model.add(tf.layers.maxPooling2d(maxPoolConf));
model.add(tf.layers.conv2d({
    kernelSize: FILTER_SIZE,
    filters: 128,
    dataFormat: "channelsLast",
    activation: ActFunc.RELU
}));
model.add(tf.layers.maxPooling2d(maxPoolConf));
model.add(tf.layers.conv2d({
    kernelSize: FILTER_SIZE,
    filters: 256,
    dataFormat: "channelsLast",
    activation: ActFunc.RELU
}));
model.add(tf.layers.maxPooling2d(maxPoolConf));
model.add(tf.layers.conv2d({
    kernelSize: FILTER_SIZE,
    filters: 512,
    dataFormat: "channelsLast",
    activation: ActFunc.RELU
}));
model.add(tf.layers.maxPooling2d(maxPoolConf));
model.add(tf.layers.flatten());
model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 128, activation: 'relu'}));
model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 256, activation: 'relu'}));
model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 512, activation: 'relu'}));
model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 1024, activation: 'relu'}));
model.add(tf.layers.dense({
    units: 7,
    activation: 'softmax'
}));
model.compile({
    optimizer: 'adam',
    loss: 'categoricalCrossentropy',
    metrics: ['accuracy', 'categoricalCrossentropy']
});

let image_tensor = tf.tensor4d(training_data.getInputData(), [training_data.length, 48, 48, 1]);
let correct_prediction_tensor = tf.tensor2d(training_data.getLabels(), [training_data.length, 7]);

const history = await model.fit(image_tensor, correct_prediction_tensor,
    {
        batchSize: 128,
        epochs: 10,
        shuffle: true,
        callbacks: {
            onEpochEnd: (epoch, logs) => {
                // Plot the loss and accuracy values at the end of every training epoch.
                console.log(epoch, logs);
            },
            onTrainStart: console.log("Starting Training..."),
            onTrainEnd: console.log("Training Finished!"),
        }
    });
```

When I run this code it prints "Starting Training..." and instantly after that "Training Finished!" (it doesn't even train the model) and then my GPU has 100% load on it until I close the tab. I don't know what to do.

The input data is a 48x48 image.

`training_data.getInputData()` returns a flat array with pixel data from every image and respectively `training_data.getLabels()` returns a flat array with label data.

Answer (score 0):

`model.fit()` is an asynchronous method. You should use either `await` or `then`.

For example, with `await` (since ES2017):

```js
  const history = await model.fit(image_tensor, correct_prediction_tensor,
    {
        batchSize: 128,
        epochs: 10,
        shuffle: true,
        callbacks: {
            onEpochEnd: (epoch, logs) => {
                // Plot the loss and accuracy values at the end of every training epoch.
                console.log(epoch, logs);
            },
            onTrainStart: console.log("Starting Training..."),
            onTrainEnd: console.log("Training Finished!"),
        }
    });
```

Or with `then`:

```js
  model.fit(image_tensor, correct_prediction_tensor,
    {
        batchSize: 128,
        epochs: 10,
        shuffle: true,
        callbacks: {
            onEpochEnd: (epoch, logs) => {
                // Plot the loss and accuracy values at the end of every training epoch.
                console.log(epoch, logs);
            },
            onTrainStart: console.log("Starting Training..."),
            onTrainEnd: console.log("Training Finished!"),
        }
    }).then(history => {
      console.log('history:', history);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it still doesn't work. It doesn't change anything.

Comment: When it finishes instantly, do you see any error or warning messages?